# Stability of Confluence 4.0

Tags: wiki, confluence

I would appreciate feedback on experience with Confluence 4.0 from people who have implemented this version.   In particular have you found the 4.0 release stable in your environments?

Comment: Probably belongs on ServerFault, or maybe SuperUser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found it exceptional on my Ubuntu 10.10 - stable, but I'm running a limited number of users.

Installer was improved.  I miss full-page wiki markup, but clipboard support to copy and paste images directly on a page is excellent.

Personally speaking, it was worth the upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

I'm developing plugins for confluence. If you have a confluence 3.x instance with lots of 3rd party plugins - upgrading to confluence 4 won't work because most 3rd party plugins are not (yet) confluence 4 compatible. Check compatibility for each of the plugins on https://plugins.atlassian.com

Comment: Things are much better now. A lot of the plugins we use have been updated in the last month or so.